# How can I access each pixel in OpenCV, perform an operation and return the new information to the image?

Tags: image, opencv, pixel

I am trying to access each pixel of the image to perform an operation and return it back to the image, someone has some idea of ​​how to do it since I have done this but it marks me wrong when compiling.

```
 #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> 
 #include <stdio.h>

 using namespace cv;
 using namespace std;
 int main( int argc, char** argv ){

    char* source_window = "Source image";
    Mat nueva;
    Mat img = imread("img.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    unsigned char *input = (unsigned char*)(img.data);

    int i,j,b;
    for(int i = 0;i < img.cols;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < img.rows;j++){
           b = input[i+1][j+1] ;
           nueva[i][j] = b;
         }
     }

     imshow( source_window, nueva );

 }
```

Comment: What is your actual goal ? You seem to imply no `if` condition, you need to manipulate all the pixels? You may create a new `Mat` in that case.

Comment: Guess your question is not about OpenCV but about C++ compiler error message you have got. I suggest to read the error message, put it on google and try to understand why you actually are stuck in

Comment: In general, when you find yourself manually iterating over pixels of a `cv::Mat` [to perform an identical operation], it's time to stop, think and refer to the documentation. In vast majority of cases, there already exists a suitable high level abstraction that lets you achieve the same thing with less code and often better performance. Learn to use the tools the library provides. (However, judging from the code shown, you should first invest time in learning the fundamentals of C++)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that this code you could use

```
 int nl= image.rows; 
 int nc= image.cols * image.channels();
 for (int j=0; j<nl; j++) {
    uchar* data= image.ptr<uchar>(j);
    for (int i=0; i<nc; i++) {
       data[i]= data[i]/div*div + div/2;
    }
 }
```